# Convert a string list/set to json objects in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class named Order which contains one string list below

```
Set<String> items;
```

and when I convert this to JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
String JSON = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(order);
System.out.println(JSON);
```

... I get output like below

```
"items":[  
         "xyz",
         "aaa"
        ]
```

I'm looking for an output something like below

```
"items":[  
         {  
            "result":"xyz"
         },
         {  
            "result":"aaa"
         }
        ]
```

I don't want to create a class separately for a single string.

Comment: You can format code easily by indenting with four spaces, that's all you need to do.

Comment: Could you please post the entire implementation of the `Order` class and its serialization/deserialization?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov it is a plan POJO object and i'm converting my class to JSON by using the below code.`ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper(); String JSON = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(order);
                System.out.println(JSON);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use some API, like Jackson, for creating JSON object and print it into string. First create a json `ArrayNode` for your `items`. Then for each string in your `items`, create an `ObjectNode` like this,

```
ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
node.put("result", "xyz");
```

and add them to the `ArrayNode`. Finally you print the JSON object out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helps.. Is there any annotations or some way I can tell `Set<String> items` to treat it as independent string object?

Comment: you can override the `toString()` method for your `Order` class by returning a string representation of your json object